# Parsing XML with Java and the XML DOM

Tags: java, xml, dom

I am trying to parse an XML file using Java and the XML DOM. I am able to read some attributes correctly, but not lists within the XML.

For example, there's a list of labels and when I read this list, I get a NodeList with a single node, which I don't understand why as I would expect one node for each object in the list. Then, when I print the single node, I get all labels concatenated.

How can I obtain a list of labels where each object in the list is one label of the label list?

**This is my code**:

```
NodeList labelsList = elem.getElementsByTagName("labels");
                
                for (int j = 0; j < labelsList.getLength(); j++) {
                    Element label = (Element) labelsList.item(j);
                    System.out.println(label.getTextContent());
                }
```

**The XML looks like this**:

```
<item>
    <title>test</title>
    <labels>
        <label>a</labels>
        <label>b</labels>
        <label>c</labels>
    </labels>
</item>
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: `NodeList labels = labelsList.item(j).getElementsByTagName("label")` and iterate that list.

Answer (score 0):

I assum XML looks like this:

```xml
<item>
    <title>test</title>
    <labels>
        <label>a</label>
        <label>b</label>
        <label>c</label>
    </labels>
</item>
```

You have pairs `<label>` with `<labels>`. I guess there's a spelling error.

```java
    NodeList labelsList = item.getElementsByTagName("label");

    // Iterate through 'label' elements
    for (int j = 0; j < labelsList.getLength(); j++) {
        Element label = (Element) labelsList.item(j);
        // Get text content of each 'label' element
        String labelText = label.getTextContent();
        System.out.println("Label: " + labelText);
```

With this code, you can retrieve labels separately. They should not be concatenated.

If you use `NodeList labelsList = item.getElementsByTagName("labels");` The length of `labelsList` is 1.